# Android correct way to display camera

Tags: android, android-camera

I used this [tutorial](http://blog.rhesoft.com/2015/04/02/tutorial-how-to-use-camera-with-android-and-android-studio/) in order to display a preview of camera before taking shots etc, however I found `android.hardware.Camera` is deprecated and I need to use `android.hardware.camera2` instead, my question is what is the correct way to show a preview of the camera? I want my application to be able to run also on api<21 and I noticed `camera2` is for api 21.. can someone clarify this situation to me?

Comment: If your target is prior 21, should use deprecated classes. If you want you can create two implementation `android.hardware.Camera` to <21 and `camera2` to >=21. `camera2` is easier implementation then `camera`.

Comment: @betorcs I want to eventually publish this application, so people with any android version will be able to download it, I need to check if it is lower then api21 and then use deprecated classes and if it is greater then api21 to use the new classes?

Comment: Using `android.hardware.Camera` is fine to all.

Comment: @betorcs Okay, thanks :) I thought deprecated classes will not work on newer devices

Comment: Take a look on camera libs of this guy https://github.com/commonsguy. There are cool stuff, it can help you.